# Error in 1: subscript out of bounds when web-scraping for dynamic generate from JavaScript

Tags: r

I am webscraping data from ' [https://www.gov.mb.ca/sd/fire/Fire-Maps/fireview/fireview.html'](https://www.gov.mb.ca/sd/fire/Fire-Maps/fireview/fireview.html%27). The final purpose is to export it to SQL, so I would like to have rows and column. Ideally I would also like to get the lat-long from the "fire report" link.

Thanks!

```
library('rvest')
url_Manitoba2 <- 'https://www.gov.mb.ca/sd/fire/Fire- Maps/fireview/fireview.html'
webpage_Manitoba2 <- read_html(url_Manitoba2)

populations <- webpage_Manitoba2 %>%
html_nodes("table") %>%
html_table(fill=TRUE)
populations [[2]]
```

Error in populations[[2]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: rvest (really `xml2::read_html`) doesn't run javascript when it grabs the HTML, so you'll have to use something more robust to scrape, after which you can still parse with rvest. [decapitated](https://gitlab.com/hrbrmstr/decapitated) is nice.

Comment: Is decapitated a package in R? How do I download it?
Plus what does "::" mean plz? Sorry i have very basic knowledge of R/ webscrapping

Comment: It is an R package, but it's not on CRAN. You can install it with `devtools::install_gitlab("hrbrmstr/decapitated")`, assuming you already have devtools installed. If you don't, do `install.packages('devtools')` first. `::` is a way to call a function from a package without explicitly loading that package, so `xml2` is the package and `read_html` is the function. More generally, this is a hard page to scrape. It looks like the data is loaded in [the shapefile](https://www.gov.mb.ca/sd/fire/Fire-Maps/MB_Forest_Fires_Shapefile.zip), which you can load with [sf](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/)

Comment: Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open destfile 'C:\Users\NCHINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpYZquzq\file657c36e05c73', reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection

I have this answer when I try to install it. The website cran doesnt load too so maybe it's blocked by network security at my office? Thanks!